# when i want to install pip in python i get this erorr? there is solution?

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install `pip` I get this erorr, I tried uninstalling and install python again, without any result.
For example if I want to install the `random` module via pip I get this error:

```
C:\Users\nadzi>pip install random
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for random
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\nadzi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install `random` via PIP? Are you aware that that's a built-in Python package?

Answer (score 1):

It's already there just use it by typing import random

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `pip install random`. Just do `import random`

Answer (score 0):

The `random` module is in the **[python standard library.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/)** Just use `import random` to import it. You don't need to install it.

Comment: win i run the script i get this error `PS C:\Users\nadzi>

  File "c:\Users\nadzi\OneDrive\Bureau\ran.py", line 2, in <module>
    import random
  File "c:\Users\nadzi\OneDrive\Bureau\random.py", line 14, in <module>
    print (ran_gen(8, "AEIOSUMA23"))
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
  File "c:\Users\nadzi\OneDrive\Bureau\random.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'choice' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Comment: A cicular import occurs when module A imports module B, while module B imports something from module A. Did you name your file one of `random`'s imported modules?

Answer (score 0):

The random module is inbuilt in python so you don't need to install it via pip.